# Postgres Get Max or Min of Tuple/Record

Tags: postgresql

How do I get a min or max of a record in postgres?

For example:

```sql
SELECT 
   max(num), max(letter)
FROM (
   VALUES 
      (1, 'c'), 
      (3, 'a'),
      (3, 'b')
) AS t (num,letter);
```

Will give me `(3, 'c')`.

The problem is that you can't do `max(ROW(num, letter))`.

However I'd like a function that finds the max value of a tuple, which would be in python

```
>>> max([
   (1, 'c'),
   (3, 'a'),
   (3, 'b'),
])
(3, 'b')
```

Is there a way to get this in Postgres easily?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `LIMIT` query here, with two sort levels for the two columns:

```sql
SELECT num, letter
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY num DESC, letter DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In the event that there could be two or more records "tied" as being first, then use `RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY num DESC, letter DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT num, letter
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Eh, doesn't work too well in my case because I have to do this as a window function.

Comment: I have also given you a window function option.  Use `RANK()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NOT EXISTS(...)`, and compare complete tuples:

---

```
WITH stuff (num,letter) AS(
   VALUES
      (1, 'c'),
      (3, 'a'),
      (3, 'b')
)
SELECT num,letter
FROM stuff t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM stuff nx
        WHERE (nx.num, nx.letter) > (t1.num, t1.letter)
        );
```

---

Simplified:

---

```
WITH stuff (num,letter) AS(
   VALUES
      (1, 'c'),
      (3, 'a'),
      (3, 'b')
)
SELECT num,letter
FROM stuff t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM stuff nx
        WHERE (nx.*) > (t1.*)
        );
```

---

Simplified:

---

```
WITH stuff (num,letter) AS(
   VALUES
      (1, 'c'),
      (3, 'a'),
      (3, 'b')
)
SELECT num,letter
FROM stuff t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM stuff nx
        WHERE (nx) > (t1)
        );
```